# jekyll highlight tag breaks markdown syntax

Tags: jekyll, pygments

Say I have the following in a jekyll post:

```
{% highlight ruby linenos %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}


## an h2
```

The highlighting works correctly with me using pygments, but I get the literal "## an h2" in my post.  All markdown syntax does not work correctly after a highlight block for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was converting some stuff from HTML over to jekyll/markdown and had left an HTML tag open at the bottom of the document.  When I removed the open tag, things went back to normal.

Comment: You should accept your answer to show that the problem is solved.